# Flux compactifications and the scalar potential

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, supergravity, moduli, string-field-theory

Does the scalar potential:

$$V=e^K(K^{I \bar{J}})D_IW D_{\bar{J}}\bar{W}-3|W|^2$$

where $K$ is the Kähler potential and $W$ the superpotential, $D=\partial_I+\partial_IK$ and $I$ runs over all the moduli,
arise **because** of the presence of fluxes?

If the fluxes are "turned off", does this mean $F_3=0$ and $H_3=0$, or that the integral of these field strengths over a particular cycle is zero (*i.e.* there are no non-trivial sources available in the theory)?

I usually see the $F_3$ and $H_3$ referred to as fluxes but I always thought these were field strengths.

To be specific this whole confusion arises from studying [*The Effective Action of $\mathcal{N}= 1$ Calabi-Yau orientifolds*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403067). Footnote $9$ says not having fluxes would result in not having the $V$ potential in the $4$D action; wouldn't also the kinetic terms for the field strength vanish?

Comment: Please *always* define your notation. I can *guess* what those objects are, but it is much better if your question briefly says what all those variables are supposed to be.

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/37909